# How to Add the test result to existing extent report without replacing the existing results in the report file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am using extentReport version 4.

```
htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./Reports/URL" + count + "/ImageCaptureApp.html");
        htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("ImageCapture - Fanvoice Automation");
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Fanvoice Automation extentTest Results. " + baseurl + "");

        extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        extentReports.setSystemInfo("Organization", "FanKave");
        extentReports.setSystemInfo("Browser", "Chrome");
        extentReports.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
```

Now I have 2 different URLs and for both URLs, I have 2 different test classes with 4 test cases in each.
I want to capture only failed test cases and shown in one report.
For loop1, everything works fine and results are flushed into the Extent Report successfully.
For the second loop, when the results are flushed, the old results erased. I want to add the new results without erasing the old one. Please help. Thank you